# Inverse of Z-Normalize (z-score) Function on Matlab

Tags: matlab, inverse

In Matlab R2014a I am confident of using **zscore(x)** function

```
function [z,mu,sigma] = zscore(x,flag,dim)
if isequal(x,[]), z = []; return; end

if nargin < 2
    flag = 0;
end
if nargin < 3
    % Figure out which dimension to work along.
    dim = find(size(x) ~= 1, 1);
    if isempty(dim), dim = 1; end
end

% Compute X's mean and sd, and standardize it
mu = mean(x,dim);
sigma = std(x,flag,dim);
sigma0 = sigma;
sigma0(sigma0==0) = 1;
z = bsxfun(@minus,x, mu);
z = bsxfun(@rdivide, z, sigma0);
```

which x is an array (1x12 double) of a time series. The formula for z is basically: **z = (x - mean)/stdDev** 
lets say x is initially set to :

> x =
>    Columns 1 through 5>>
>    40.466666670000002  43.538461540000000  40.466666670000002  41.846153850000000  46.266666669999999
>    Columns 6 through 10>>
>    68.000000000000000  87.200000000000003  42.933333330000004  41.071428570000002  41.428571429999998
>    Columns 11 through 12>>
>    83.200000000000003  96.076923080000000

After I run

```
x=zscore(x);
```

It becomes as below:

> x =
>    Columns 1 through 5>>
>    -0.730346157143482  -0.586298957286754  -0.730346157143482  -0.665657180852154  -0.458363881462091
>    Columns 6 through 10>>
>     0.560788093923360   1.461143213420378  -0.614675534465169  -0.701986757521516  -0.685239080313558
>    Columns 11 through 12>>
>     1.273569230191833   1.877413168652630

I need to apply its inverse function. How should I implement the code on Matlab.

Comment: you mean how to find `x` from `z`? I don't understand haha sorry.

Comment: No worries... Mathematically speaking, I want **x = z(StdDev) + mean** (this) functions code, as I already know **z = (x - mean)/stdDev** (that) as zscore function

Comment: ok so then isn't it simply `z = (x-mean(x,dim))./sigma0`?

Comment: It doesn't give me the correct results. `mean(x,2)` gives:  _-2.405483220021172e-16_ whereas `sigma0` returns _1_

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the inverse you will need to know the mean and standard deviation of the original x, as there are there are many values of the input which can result in the same z scores. As I think you've realised the mean and standard deviaiton of the z-scores are always 0 and 1 respectively, by the definition of the z-score and so give no useful information.

If you know the original mean and standard deviation. You can calculate the original x simply as **x=std(x)*z+mean(x)**. However, if you don't then the problem is not well defined and can't be solved.

As an example of this if you add 100 to all your original data, the z-scores are unchanged. There is not way of distinguishing which x value is correct from the z-score alone. The same if you multiply the original data by a constant.

Comment: Thanks, It is true that I need to know the mean and sigma of the original x to calculate inverse fuction of the zscore. For this unknowns I am gonna apply another array's std deviation and mean onto my original x's zscore.