# Reverse Z Scores

Tags: r, standardized

If you have a data vector you are given that contains only z-scored variables is it possible to reverse the z-score values to get the original measure without using the original measure?
In R Program:

```
a = runif(100)
az = (a - mean(a))/sd(a)
```

Can you get back 'a' using JUST 'az'?

Comment: No, as mentioned here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479024/inverse-of-z-normalize-z-score-function-on-matlab)

Comment: No, information is lost in the transformation. If you don't record the original mean and sd, there is no going back. (Imagine the case of a single data point - if I give you a `4`, and tell you "Hey, I started with a number `x`, I subtracted a number `m`, and then divided by a number `s`, and `(x - m) / s = 4`. What was the original `x`?", there is no way you can answer without knowing both `m` and `s`.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The reverse transformation requires knowledge of the summary statistics `mean(a)` and `sd(a)`, which cannot be recovered from the standardized scores.